# How to make semi-transparent panel in Delphi VCL

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.3-rio

I can easily make semi-transparent panel inside form using Firemonkey's **TForm.Transparency** and **TPanel.Opacity** options. But I can't do it in VCL.

I want to make something like this:

[image]

Is there any way to do it in VCL application? No third-party component please.

Edit: If I can also make opaque components on the semi-transparent surface, that would be a PLUS.

Comment: Instead of a `TPanel` use a form with `AlphaBlend = True` and `AlphaBlendValue = 127`. If the form's borders disturb, set `BorderStyle = bsNone`

Comment: @TomBrunberg How will I make opaque components then?

Comment: But the image (that you said is what you want) has semi opaque buttons? So, what do you want? Be specific, please.

Comment: And since Windows 8 child windows can be layered too.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Image is from Firemonkey app. I want to do it using VCL.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But what about component opacity? See your first comment and my response.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I want semi-opaque and full-opaque components inside the same form. If I use AlphaBlend, afaik i won't be able to make full-opaque components.

Comment: So, in other words, the image is NOT what you want to achieve after all (since the left button isn't fully opaque)! :)

Comment: Thanks, So please edit your question and include something like "semi-transparent surface with both semi-transparent and opaque components".

Comment: Do you need form border, title bar and buttons? Or just what you showed on the image?

Comment: @fpiette I don't need them. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Lol, stackoverflow users really will spend an entire comment thread telling you what you want isn't actually what you want instead of helping. I thought this was a meme but it's real !